# Special Order date picker that validates time frame before add to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, validation, special-price, datepicker

I am fairly new to magento2 and I am working on developing a date picker that validates if a special order can be placed in time. The time frame would be different for each manufacturer on the site and can take two types (Regular order 16 weeks, Rush Order 10 weeks). I am kind of stuck in where to start developing this.

Here is an example

http://abrideschoice.com/product/maggie-sottero-trudy-marie-bridal-gown/